# Mostrando apenas um dia no Datapicker

Tags: datepicker

Tenho 2 datapickers, como faço pra mostrar apenas aquele dia que armazenei?

código:

```
$("#data-retorno").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    return [date.getDay() == 5, ""]
                },
                onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                   var data = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', selectedDate);
                   data.setDate(data.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 1);
                   alert(data);
                   $("#data-checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", data);  
                }
            });
```

No caso neste script, a data selecionada, ele vai somar mais 1 dia,agora, como que retorno apenas esse dia no script abaixo?

```
$("#data-checkout").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    return [date.getDay() == 6, ""]
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi sua dúvida...

Comment: Nessa variável `var data = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', selectedDate);` eu armazeno um dia selecionado. E passo esse valor pro datapicker #data-checkout, só que nele, eu seto minDate, fazendo com que, retorne os sábados a partir daquela data, só que não quero que retorne a partir da data, quero que retorno apenas a data. Se o cara clicar 14 vai somar + 1 ficando 15; Não quero que retorne a partir de 15, e sim, somente o 15.

Comment: Tente informar o `minDate` e `maxDate` iguais. Ou seja os dois com a mesma data, no seu exemplo seria o dia 15. No seu caso, seria somente **adicionar** o maxDate no `onClose: $("#data-checkout").datepicker("option", "maxDate", data);`